# Memory Size Exhausted when modifying Wordpress Search Function

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I am trying to modify the search function of wordpress to disable posts that have been set to not show in the sitemap via ACF radio button.

When i navigate to the site I am greeted with this lovely error message:

```
Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 130968 bytes) in /Users/***/***/***/***/wp-includes/class-wp-query.php on line 1621
```

Code:

```
function exclude_pages_from_search($query) {
    if ( !is_admin() ) {

        $hidePages = new WP_Query( array (
            'meta_key' => 'edit_screen_sitemap',
            'meta_value' => 'hide',
            'fields' => 'ids'
        )); $hidePageIds = implode( ',', $hidePages->posts );
        //print_r($hidePageIds);

        if ( $query->is_main_query() ) {

            if ($query->is_search) {
                $query->set('post__not_in', array($hidePageIds));
            }
        }
    }
}

add_action('pre_get_posts','exclude_pages_from_search');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to remove your action from your own query. Otherwise your function will call itself recursively, and exhaust the memory due to infinite recursion. This should do the trick:

```
// remove our action temporarily 
remove_action('pre_get_posts','exclude_pages_from_search');

$hidePages = new WP_Query( array ( ... //your query
$hidePageIds = implode( ',', $hidePages->posts );

// add the action again
add_action('pre_get_posts','exclude_pages_from_search'); 

if ... //rest of your function
```

Comment: thanks I changed the ordering around, now when I var_dump($hidePageIds) it displays: string(0) "". Checking the database i can see post id 373 has edit_screen_sitemap as "hide". Any idea?

Comment: Not sure; could you try `$query->set('post__not_in', $hidePages);` and `$query->set('post__not_in', array($hidePages->posts));`. The docs say that posts__not_in needs an integer array, and does not parse a comma separated list.

Comment: The following is what is displayed:

https://hastebin.com/awiganozur.php it doesn't give me the IDs of the queried

Comment: I have created a new question as it's no longer relational to the original question here. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52932829/wp-query-not-returning-the-ids-for-use-in-search-query

Comment: Good. That's the best way to get some fresh eyes looking at the question.