# WP_Query Not Returning The ID for use in Search Query

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to retrieve a list of IDs to remove from the search query based off of a WP_Query. For whatever reason the WP_Query is not displaying an array of IDs even though I know that post id 373 has the correct conditions of the query.

```
remove_action('pre_get_posts','exclude_pages_from_search');

$hidePages = new WP_Query( array (
    'meta_key' => 'edit_screen_sitemap',
    'meta_value' => 'hide',
    'fields' => 'ids'
)); 

$hidePageIds = array($hidePages->posts);
$hidePageIdss = array($hidePages);

var_dump($hidePageIds); // array(1) { [0]=> array(0) { } }
var_dump($hidePageIdss); // displays query array

add_action('pre_get_posts','exclude_pages_from_search');

function exclude_pages_from_search($query) {
    if ( !is_admin() ) {

        if ( $query->is_main_query() ) {

            if ($query->is_search) {
                $query->set('post__not_in', array($hidePages->posts));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some investigation I found that by default the post loop uses only the post type of "post". I had to define all the post types I wanted to search for in order for it to bring back the ID of the page/custom post type that matched the values:

```
remove_action('pre_get_posts','exclude_pages_from_search');

$hidePages = new WP_Query( array (
    'post_type' => array( 'post', 'page', 'offer', 'review', 'project' ),
    'meta_key' => 'edit_screen_sitemap',
    'meta_value' => 'hide',
    'fields' => 'ids'
)); 

$hidePageIds = array($hidePages->posts);
$hidePageIdss = array($hidePages);

var_dump($hidePageIds); // array(1) { [0]=> array(0) { } }
var_dump($hidePageIdss); // displays query array

add_action('pre_get_posts','exclude_pages_from_search');

function exclude_pages_from_search($query) {
    if ( !is_admin() ) {

        if ( $query->is_main_query() ) {

            if ($query->is_search) {
                $query->set('post__not_in', array($hidePages->posts));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Please note, this only fixes the issues of getting the page ids, it does not make the search function work I have another issue located here where you may find the fixed query: [post__not_in is not excluding IDs from Wordpress Search Query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52947360/post-not-in-is-not-excluding-ids-from-wordpress-search-query)