# post__not_in is not excluding IDs from Wordpress Search Query

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to retrieve the IDs of posts with a certain meta value (this works fine) I then try to pass them through post__not_in and it does not exclude the posts from the wordpress search.

I have the integer array (from a var_dump):

```
array(2) { [0]=> int(373) [1]=> int(247) }
```

However, I now need to convert that array into 373,247 for use in post__not_in. Any ideas?

```
remove_action('pre_get_posts','exclude_pages_from_search');

$hidePages = new WP_Query( array (
    'post_type' => array( 'post', 'page', 'offer', 'review', 'project' ),
    'ignore_sticky_posts' => true,
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'meta_key' => 'edit_screen_sitemap',
    'meta_value' => 'hide',
    'fields' => 'ids'
));

$test = $hidePages->posts;

function exclude_pages_from_search($query) {
    if ( !is_admin() ) {

        if ( $query->is_main_query() ) {

            if ($query->is_search) {
                $query->set('post__not_in', $test);
            }
        }
    }
} add_action('pre_get_posts','exclude_pages_from_search');
```

Comment: your variable `$hidePageInt` has nothing to exclude

Comment: @raju_eww small type error, amended issue still occurs obviously as the issue is getting the correct format value over there :)

Comment: https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query explicitly says that `post__not_in` needs to be passed an array of post ids, so do you think you had to _“convert that into 373,247”_ in the first place? Do a var_dump of your $test variable and check what that actually contains.

Comment: Already var_dumped you can see it in the question. I passed the $test into the post__not_in and it didn't work.

Comment: Go enable proper PHP error reporting and/or WP debug mode. Inside the function `exclude_pages_from_search`, there is no variable named `$test` available to begin with. (And wrapping it in `array()` again would also be wrong.)

Comment: 0 php errors but wp_debug says undefined variable. moved everything inside the function and the query causes a max memory size. How do I allow the variable to be used in the function when it causes a memory leak...

Comment: global $test; added this inside query loop and it worked. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue I was orginally having was I was imploding the array and turning it into a string when I needed an integer array. So I removed the imploding of the Query and left it as a variable which of course became an integer array as post___not_in only allows integer arrays.

I then ran into the trouble of a memory leak if I ran the query inside the function so I had to figure out how to run it outside the function and still be able to use the variable inside the function as it would be undefined.

With the addition of global $hidePageIds, I was able to access the variable holding the integer array inside the function and therefore pass it in the post__not_in query.

```
remove_action('pre_get_posts','exclude_pages_from_search');

$hidePages = new WP_Query( array (
    'post_type' => array( 'post', 'page', 'offer', 'review', 'project' ),
    'ignore_sticky_posts' => true,
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'meta_key' => 'edit_screen_sitemap',
    'meta_value' => 'hide',
    'fields' => 'ids'
));

$hidePageIds = $hidePages->posts;

function exclude_pages_from_search($query) {
    if ( !is_admin() ) {

        if ( $query->is_main_query() ) {

            if ($query->is_search) {

                global $hidePageIds;
                $query->set('post__not_in', $hidePageIds);
            }
        }
    }
} add_action('pre_get_posts','exclude_pages_from_search');
```